# How do you set page title for the specific ID pages of a paramID using JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, title, tiles

Using Tiles and JSPs.  On a JSP, using `${param.ID}` to get specific pages.

`sub-category.jsp`

```
<jsp:include page="categories/sub-category/${param.ID}.jsp" flush="true" />
```

`/sub-category/test-page.jsp` is an ID

I need to find a way to make `test-page.jsp` have its own unique page title that I can insert onto `test-page.jsp`.

Comment: Your question is confusing. How does Tiles play a role here? If you were really using Tiles, why are you using `<jsp:include>` instead of Tiles? Also, how exactly does [JSTL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) play a role here? Do you know what it is? Aren't you confusing [EL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) with JSTL?

Comment: Using tiles for the layout.  'getAsString' for the title doesn't work for paramID that I've found.  Like I said, very new to JSTL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assuming that you want to change the title of your webpage based on the page loaded(eg. test-page.jsp).

If that is true, then in test-page.jsp, you can write

```
<script>
    document.title = "My Title";
</script>
```

or write within document.onload()

best would be jquery.ready function

Comment: t/y for answering.  Pretty much what you said. I'm looking for solution for the ID jsp page that the paramID calls. So a unique page title inside each unique ID page.  I've read that a script title is bad for SEO, so looking for any server-side solution if there is one. I don't care what it is as long as it works and won't mess up SEO.

Comment: True. SEO will not identify these values.. the other option to set the title directly. <head><title><%= param.name %></title></head>

Comment: This gave me the error -- "param cannot be resolved to a variable"